# How to tell Typescript that a field in an object specifies the type of another field?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types

I have a type like this:

```
type Event = {
  ts: Date,
  type: 'birthday' | 'wedding',
  event: Birthday | Wedding
}
```

Currently, I have to use type-narrowing fields on the `event` field:

```
if ('partners' in evt.event) {
  // ts knows evt.event is Wedding
  sendWeddingInvite(evt.event)
} else {
  // ts thinks it's Birthday, the only remaining option
}
```

I would like to use the `type` field instead. Is there any better option than:

```
if (evt.type === 'wedding') {
  sendWeddingInvite(evt.event as Wedding)
}
```

Comment: Just use [a discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have two types of event, you can use something like this:

```
type Event = { ts: Date } & ({ type: 'birthday', event: Birthday } | { type: 'wedding', event: Wedding })
```

So when the `type` is detected to be 'wedding', the `event` must be of type `Wedding`, and when the `type` is detected to be 'birthday', the `event` must be of type `Birthday`.

But if you expect the number of types of event to increase, it may be troublesome to keep adding unions that way.
However, it is possible to automatically generate that type of unions by using distributive conditional types.

```
type EventTypesMap = {
  birthday: Birthday,
  wedding: Wedding
}

//take advantage of distributive conditional types 
type TypeAndEventObj<T extends keyof EventTypesMap> = T extends any ? {
  type: T,
  event: EventTypesMap[T]
} : never;

// This way, TypeAndEventObj<'birthday' | 'wedding'> will become
//({ type: 'birthday', event: Birthday } | { type: 'wedding', event: Wedding })

type Event = { ts: Date } & TypeAndEventObj<keyof EventTypesMap>;

let evt: Event

if (evt.type === 'wedding') {
  sendWeddingInvite(evt.event); //evt.event is inferred to be of type Wedding
} else {
   //evt.event is inferred to be of type Birthday here
}
```

Comment: this is great. i'm not sure i understand the conditional part ( `T extends any ?` , ` : never` ) -- why not just declare `TypeAndEventObj` straightaway?

Comment: @IgorSerebryany You can refer to https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types (bottom section). 
It only works that way when there is a conditional.  If I don't use `T extends any ? ... : never`, I would get `{ type: 'birthday' | 'wedding', event: Birthday | Wedding }` which is different from `({ type: 'birthday', event: Birthday } | { type: 'wedding', event: Wedding })`